# Correct way to model my analytics in Cassandra (Video Views)

Tags: cassandra, cql, modeling

We are (potentially) going to have a table with 3 fields

```
view_id string  (uuid)
video_id uint (this is a mysql id we use to track what video was viewed)
local    string (this is the location the video was viewed from)
```

my question is would it be better to store this as each view is an individual record, or should I store each view in a collection inside one record with a video id.

Some of the videos get 500k+ views - many get 5-10k per day.

The queries we need to run are in laymans terms

```
// Heres a video ID, where is it popular
// Heres a video ID, get all views
// Get all videos where local is some local
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection are used for small amount of data.
Collection Limitation :

- Collection (List): collection size: 2B (2^31); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)
- Collection (Set): collection size: 2B (2^31); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)
- Collection (Map): collection size: 2B (2^31); number of keys: 65535 (2^16-1); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)

And also you can't page through collection item.

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

It is better to store each view as individual record like :

```
CREATE TABLE views (
    video_id bigint,
    view_id uuid,
    local text,
    PRIMARY KEY(video_id, view_id)
);

CREATE TABLE videobylocal (
    local text,
    video_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY(local, video_id)
);
```

So To get all views of a video :

```
SELECT * FROM views WHERE video_id = ?
```

And To get all video from a location :

```
SELECT * FROM videobylocal WHERE local = ?
```

To get popular video, you have to use Spark/Hadoop or write your own program to calculate popularity.

Comment: the author asks for 500k+ views for a video, that doesn't seem to hit the 2 billion limitation any time soon, does it? also, if the author only needs videos for a location (not views), an index on `views (local)` seems to be a bit wasteful

Comment: @starikoff Let's say video view don't hit 2B, it hit 500k And you want to get all the view of that video, Is it reasonable to select 500k, item in a single select ? And my answer updated

Comment: I agree with the paging argument, it's just that the whole limitations part seems to be irrelevant in this case; btw and not really related, in 3.1 the 64k limitation on collection element sizes was removed in [CASSANDRA-10374](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10374)